# Are questions about antique tool restoration on topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I am into restoring antique woodworking tools, mostly for personal use in my shop.

Some questions about this topic are clearly within the scope of woodworking.se. For example,

- how to use a planemaker's float to open up the mouth on a moulding plane
- how to repair nicked up wooden screws on a wooden plough plane

But other questions are not as clear. For example,

- questions about rust electrolysis
- how to make authentic japanning

I can see a few places where the line could be drawn. When does the community consider such questions off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

Great question!  Fixing or restoring woodworking tools is mostly on topic here, but if the fix requires tools or expertise not normally found in a woodworking shop, (say welding or your electrolysis example) then it probably doesn't belong here.  I myself tend to be more inclusive than exclusive on questions when they actually are asked though.

> how to make authentic japanning

here, it's more likely to be fine, since it is a technique for finishing a piece of woodwork, and finishing is definitely on topic.